# Cannot calculate values for input values and error says: String empty

Tags: java, eclipse, model-view-controller

I could not perform the calculation. the values cannot be displayed because of the error: 
**java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String**

I got this code for my controller:

```
        public class Calculate {
             private MainFrame MainFrame;
             private CalculatorModel CalculatorModel;
                public Calculate(MainFrame MainFrame, CalculatorModel CalculatorModel){
                    this.MainFrame = MainFrame;   
                    this. CalculatorModel = CalculatorModel;
                }

                public void CalculateTotalCash() {
                    ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {  
                            double textField_6 ,textField_7 ,textField_8, textField_15, textField_16, textField_17, textField_18, textField_19, textField_20, textField_21 = 0;
                            try {
                                textField_6 = Double.parseDouble(MainFrame.textField_6.getText());
                                textField_7 = Double.parseDouble(MainFrame.textField_7.getText());
                                textField_8 =  Double.parseDouble(MainFrame.textField_8.getText());
                                textField_15 = Double.parseDouble(MainFrame.textField_15.getText());
                                textField_16 = Double.parseDouble(MainFrame.textField_16.getText());
                                textField_17 = Double.parseDouble(MainFrame.textField_17.getText());
                                textField_18 = Double.parseDouble(MainFrame.textField_18.getText());
                                textField_19 = Double.parseDouble(MainFrame.textField_19.getText());
                                textField_20 = Double.parseDouble(MainFrame.textField_20.getText());
                                textField_21 = Double.parseDouble(MainFrame.textField_21.getText());

                                CalculatorModel.addAll(textField_6, textField_7,textField_8,textField_15,textField_16,textField_17,textField_18,textField_19,textField_20,textField_21);


   MainFrame.textField_22.setText(Double.toString(CalculatorModel.getAnswer()));

                            }catch(NumberFormatException ex){
                                System.out.println(ex);

                                MainFrame.displayErrorMessage("Please Fill in All Fields...");

                            }                               
                        }

                    };                
                  MainFrame.CalculateCashDrawer().addActionListener(actionListener); 

                }
        }
```

And I got this code for my Model:

```
public class CalculatorModel {

    private double answer;

    public void addAll(double textField_6, double textField_7, double textField_8, double textField_15, double textField_16, 
            double textField_17, double textField_18, double textField_19, double textField_20, double textField_21) {
        answer = (0.5 * textField_6) + (0.25 * textField_7) + textField_8 + (10 * textField_15) + (50 * textField_16) 
                + (20 * textField_17) + (100 * textField_18) + (200 * textField_19) + (1000 * textField_20) + (2000 * textField_21);

    }

    public double getAnswer() {
        return answer;
    }

}
```

I input values to all textfields and clicked the button calculate but then the error appears. Whats wrong with it?

Comment: One of the Mainframe.textField_**.getText() is returning empty and trying to parse that to a double object gives you the exception. Use debugger or log and find out which of the text field is returning empty string.

Comment: Please add stack trace from `ex.printStackTrace`. It's likey that one of the field is empty and it is throwing Parse Exception.

Comment: number format exception comes when you try to convert string to a number may be int long etc

Comment: how to correct a text field that is returning empty?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my error was just i am calling the wrong jtextfield. JTextField_6 must be JTextField_60.